# Can you use rowSums to select for rows that commonly have value '1', but exclude rows if all columns have value '1'?

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 30 bacteria (columns), and the genes they have (rows). Values in the data frame are **0** if the bacteria lacks the gene, while values are **1** when bacteria have the gene.

I want to see which genes are common but still vary between the 30 bacteria and the genes that are rarely found.

`cleansymbols3` is my data frame and I want to create a new data frame, `commonsymbols` that contains only genes that are found in at least 20, but not all, bacteria.

The line below selects genes that are common in 20 or more bacteria, but how do you set a range `20:29`?

```r
commonsymbols <- cleansymbols3[rowSums(cleansymbols3) >= 20, ]
```

I tried this line

```
commonsymbols <- cleansymbols3[ which( rowSums(cleansymbols3) >= 20 | rowSums(cleansymbols3) <= 29 ), ]
```

but it selects all genes, probably because it first looks for `rowSums > 20` and then `rowSums < 29`, which together are all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` instead of `|`:

```r
commonsymbols <-
cleansymbols3[rowSums(cleansymbols3) >= 20 & rowSums(cleansymbols3) <= 29, ]
```

`|` is *OR*, but `&` is *AND*. So the code you wrote is looking for rows where the rowsum is *either* greater than 20, *or* less than 30. Literally every number there is satisfies those criteria!

Using `&` looks only for rows in which the rowsum is both greater that 20, **and** less than 30. That is, it's between those two values.

#### PS I removed `which()`

You don't need to use which in this context, because `x[c(2,4,5)]` is equivalent to `x[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)]`

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative answer using `dplyr`

You could also do this using the `dplry` package:

```r
require(dplyr)

commonsymbols <- 
  rowwise(cleansymbols3) |> 
  mutate(total = sum(c_across())) |> 
  filter(total > 20, total < 30) |> 
  select(-total)
```